# Need a regex to match a single character or word but should not match substrings

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following sample text:

I want to replace all instances of `;`,`:`,`,`,`.`,`and`,`a`,`an`,`the` with pipe `|` symbol.

So the output should be something like:

I tried with the following regex but i am not getting a generic regex which matches for all:

```
"\/(^|\\W);($|\\W)\/",
"\/(^|\\W):($|\\W)\/",
"\/(^|\\W),($|\\W)\/",
"\/(^|\\W).($|\\W)\/",
"\/(^|\\W)and($|\\W)\/",
"\/(^|\\W)a($|\\W)\/",
"\/(^|\\W)an($|\\W)\/",
"\/(^|\\W)the($|\\W)\/",
"\/(^|\\W)said($|\\W)\/",
```

Also tried:

```
(?<=\s)(;.)
(?<=\s)(:.)
(?<=\s)(,.)
(?<=\s)(..)
(?<=\s)(an.)
(?<=\s)(and.)
```

But does not work, please help. Please note a search for `a` should match the portion

> with **a** light emitting

but should **not** match

> *extraction*

. Similar behavior required for others.

Comment: Try using `\b` to make sure there are word boundaries on each side of the "word" you are searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are some ambiguous cases, by using below regex you are able to match those characters. Be careful about word boundary and non-word boundary meta-characters:

```
[;.,:]\B|\b(?:an?d?|the)\b
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/9G2lYb/1)

Comment: i am okay if there are multiple regexes as well. I can loop over the string array of regex and match - i did not mean to have a single regex multiple will do as well as shown in the question. I am not sure what this ` Be careful about word boundary and non-word boundary meta-characters` means

Comment: So it should be like
`Regex1 for :` `Regex2 for ;` `Regex3 for ,` `Regex4 for a` `Regex1 for an` and so on

Comment: I'm not sure why really you want one for each but if that's the case then you have them already: 1) `;\B` 2) `\.\B` 3) `:\B` 4) `,\B` 5) `\band\b` 6) `\ban\b` 7) `\ba\b` 8) `\bthe\b`

Comment: what is the difference between `\b` and `\B` also +1 for all the help

Comment: also would like to difference between `\b`,`\B`,`\W` and `\w`